# Execute mixin only when my custom module is enabled from configuration

Tags: requirejs, configurable-swatches, mixins

I've implemented `swatch-renderer-mixin` through `require-js`. It's working fine but I need to only run it when my module is enabled. What's the best way to check it in my `mixin.js` file?
This is my requirejs-config file:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
            },
            'mage/gallery/gallery': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/gallery-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the mixin as part of your custom module, then whenever the module is disabled your mixin will not load.

Comment: I've updated my answer with requirejs file code. Sorry, I don't understand how can I make mixin as part of my custom module. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Where are your JS files located, in the theme? If so you can move them over to your module and they will now be included in your module and not the theme, so when the module is disabled the files will not load. Does that help?

Comment: My JS files are in my module. and FYI, it's just like a dummy enable/disable you know, where we need to check isEnabled() at every php function. So disabling that doesn't effect JS files. What's a better way of disabling modules?

Comment: When you say disabling do you mean disabling the whole module or a custom feature flag?

Comment: I mean disabling from configurations only, the field defined by system.xml and you know it has no effect on anything when we disable our module, unless we check enabled/disable above every module feature by getting configuration value of this field